# <picture> element doesn't work correctly - works partially on new devices

Tags: html, image

I am trying to use the `<picture>` element to change the size of my logo if someone visits the website from mobile devices for example.

This is the code that I'm using :

```
<picture>
   <source srcset="http://www.pixelmedia.ro/ina/wp-content/themes/compass/ina/logo.jpg" media="(min-width: 1125px)">
   <source srcset="http://www.pixelmedia.ro/ina/wp-content/themes/compass/images/logo-mobile.jpg" media="(min-width: 768px)">
   <source srcset="http://www.pixelmedia.ro/ina/wp-content/themes/compass/images/logo-mobile.jpg" media="(max-width: 1123px)">
   <img src="http://www.pixelmedia.ro/ina/wp-content/themes/compass/ina/logo.jpg" alt="alt text examplle!">
</picture>
```

Problem is that the code works partially. For example works on my Android cell phone with latest version of Chrome but doesn't work on Iphone 6.

Works perfectly on desktop and if I resize de browser window it will change the logo. However, not the case on many new tablets.

Question is where is the problem ...

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

the `<picture>` tag is not recognized by all webbrowsers. If you only look for a resizing image, you can try the css `img,embed,object,video{ max-width:100%}` or this javascript to force browser to recognize the `<pict>` element : [picturefill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/)

Comment: Many thanks. I've just added the picturefill script in my header and problem solved :)

Answer (score -1):

The picture element is not supported on iOS Safari

http://caniuse.com/#search=picture